# Shiny in R: selected inputs cleared out

Tags: r, select, shiny

I'm building a simple Shiny App in R with two `selectizeInput` where you can choose agencies from a list of 3 agencies, and transporters from a list of 9 transporters. My App has a strange behaviour that it clears out the choice the users made.

Let's say I do not check "Select All" but instead select something(for example, Agency A) from the Agency list like below

[image]

Then from the Transporters list, I select something (for example Transporter A2 and Transporter B2) instead of checking "Select All".

[image]

A weird thing happens here. When I go back to the Agencies list again, my choice(Agency A) is somehow cleared out.

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone tells me what the cause of this strange behaviour is, and how to solve this issue!

my data looks like this.

```
Agencies    Transporters    Ontime_rate
agency A    Transporter A1  2       
agency A    Transporter A2  5       
agency A    Transporter A3  7       
Agency B    Transporter B1  3       
Agency B    Transporter B2  5       
Agency B    Transporter B3  7       
Agency C    Transporter C1  8       
Agency C    Transporter C2  4       
Agency C    Transporter C3  10
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()

# Sidebar elements for the search visualizations
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = h5('Agencies'),
             checkboxInput('bar_agen', 'Select All', value = TRUE),
             selectizeInput('agen', label = '', choices = c(), multiple = TRUE)
             ),

    menuItem(text = h5('Transporters'),
             checkboxInput('bar_trans', 'Select All', value = TRUE),
             selectizeInput('trans', label = '', choices = c(), multiple = TRUE)
    )
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

dashboardPage(title ='Dashboard', header, sidebar, body)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("data.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  ggplot(data, aes(input$agen, y = Ontime_rate)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data = data) + geom_histogram()

    observe({

      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           'agen',
                           label = NULL,
                           choices = data$Agencies,
                           selected = if (input$bar_agen) data$Agencies)

      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           'trans',
                           label = NULL,
                           choices = data$Transporters,
                           selected = if (input$bar_trans) data$Transporters)
      })
  })
})
```

*This App is not complete yet(it doesn't return any plots in `dashboardBody`.) But I think it's not relevant to this problem. Please just focus on the sidebar inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `observe` statements inside `renderPlot` does not make sense in this instance. Instead, you want to make sure that

1. The selection for the agencies depends on the checkbox for the agencies
2. The selection for the transporters depends on the checkbox for the transporters.

You can use two seperate `observeEvent` statements for that

```
observeEvent(input$bar_agen, {
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'agen', label = NULL, choices = data$Agencies,
                       selected = if (input$bar_agen) data$Agencies
  )
})

observeEvent(input$bar_trans, {
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'agen', label = NULL, choices = data$Transporters,
                       selected = if (input$bar_trans) data$Transporters
  )
})
```

The way you coded it, the update events for both checkboxes where coupled, so the first `selectInput` got reset by the second `checkboxInput` and vice versa.